# How to create a type definition for local variable inside lambda?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, uwp

So I decided to add proprietary method to an instance of a class but that killed my type information. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
window.onload = async () => {

    let picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker()
    picker.fileTypeFilter.append("*")
    let files = await (await picker.pickSingleFolderAsync()).getFilesAsync(),
    file = files.filter(value => value.fileType == ".RMX").pop(),

    zonefiles = files.filter(value => value.fileType.startsWith(".Z"))

    console.log(file.name)

    console.log(zonefiles)

    const openedfile = await file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)

    openedfile.createreaderat = at => {
        const reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(this.getInputStreamAt(at))
        reader.byteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.littleEndian
        return reader
    }

    let datareader = openedfile.createreaderat(0) //gets type of any
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2017 community edition and I've created an UWP JS app.

Any ideas how will the d.ts file would look like so that it mitigates the issue and gives my `datareader` appropriate type?

I'm assuming something like that should work but it's giving me syntax errors:

```
window.onload = async () => {
    const openedfile: { ...: Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream, 
            createreaderat: (at: number) => Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader}
}
```

Comment: You need types for ` createreaderat` method, if the original object is not yours, then you need to extend that object and add new method with proper types in d.ts file. But you don't need to use d.ts file. You can use `at => { ...}: Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader;`

Comment: @jcubic I want to preserve writing in js if possible but add the types in additional file `d.ts`.

Comment: What is `Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker`? Is this a library is this interface in d.ts file or typescript class?

Comment: What is the type of `openedfile`? Does it exist in the `.d.ts` file? If it does, could you add it to your post? (if the `.d.ts` is not too big, it would be best if you posted all the relevant existing types, `FolderPicker` and the types it uses in its definition).

Comment: It's UWP. Both of those identifiers exists in a .d.ts file that's included with the SDK. I mean the second one `openedfile` is inherited from the method call.

Comment: If `Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker` is typescript class I don't think you can extend it with d.ts. file you will need to modify it's code. If it's interface then you can overwrite interface with same signature and adding new function inside, check my d.ts file jQuery terminal where I've added new methods. [jquery.terminal.d.ts#L257](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/js/jquery.terminal.d.ts#L257).

Comment: It's rather `Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream`

Comment: I don't know what `openAsync` returns, you have whole code I can only see few lines. Whatever that function return, if it's interface you can modify it but I think that it's typescript class you can patch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
openedfile.createreaderat = at => <Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader>({
    const reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(this.getInputStreamAt(at));
    reader.byteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.littleEndian;
    return reader;
});
```